# HTTP Request Body Call Out Salesforce Apex

Tags: apex, rest-api, httprequest

I just want to call an API  from an Apex. But all i know how to do is thru JSON String for the body. The integration team required me to call it thru Data Form which i can call it from Post. I got no idea how will create or send the request body on the API using Data Form Format.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To send a request with a data form format in Salesforce Apex, you can use the HttpRequest class. You need to set the content type of the request to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' and encode the data form fields in the request body as a key-value pair. Here is an example:

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setEndpoint('https://your-api-endpoint.com');
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

String body = 'field1=value1&field2=value2';
req.setBody(body);

Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
```

Comment: I am wondering why this was not marked as answer.